# Multiple Jquery selectors?

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to solve an issue and create cleaner code than spending time duplicating the same code over and over again. Currently I have:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('#hidden85').css({opacity:0}); // hide hidden element first
jQuery("#configproduct1").hover(function() { // if trigger is hovered over
jQuery('#hidden85').animate ({opacity: 1}, 250); // reveal the hidden element
}, function() { // if mouse leaves the hover area
jQuery('#hidden85').animate ({opacity: 0}, 250);}); // hide the hidden element again
});
```

This code hides part of a set of nested divs, one an image and one text. when a user hovers the image the text div appears.

This works fine for the one div with the ID #Hidden85. However I have multiple nested div groups on the page. Each has their own ID, sequentially going from #Hidden67 to #Hidden92 and also #configproduct1 sequentially going up as well.

rather than duplicate this code over and over again and just change the ID is there a better way to set a range for between 67 - 92 for instance in one query?

I hope that makes sense!

Thanks

Comment: is `hidden85` nested under `configproduct1`?

Comment: Use a class on all of the elements with the same behaviour and target using that - this question has been answered hundreds of times on StackOverflow

Comment: Can you add them a class just so you can use in the selector?

Comment: assign all similar elements to a class. then you can just access all elements like `$(".myClass").css`

Comment: Hello, I appreciate all your replies and responses. I'm using this code on this page:

http://kyntronics.under-development.info/product-configurator

As you can see each of the images has the text div over the top, only the second one fro the top right currently works when hovered. What I need is to be able to hide all the text boxes, then only show the one on the image hovered over? This is why I thought I needed separate DIV and class elements.

Comment: There is an error on that page - a missing closing quote (`jQuery('#hidden85).css({opacity:0});`) - so *nothing* works on that page

Answer (score -1):

On all the `DIV` that you would like to group add a common class e.g. "hidden" or "configproduct" like so:

```
<div id="hidden1" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="hidden2" class="hidden"></div>
<div id="configproduct1" class="configproduct"></div>
<div id="configproduct2" class="configproduct"></div>
```

And access them using:

```
jQuery('.hidden')
```

And

```
jQuery('.configproduct')
```

Complete:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ()
{
    jQuery('.hidden').css({ opacity: 0 }); // hide hidden element first

    jQuery(".configproduct").hover(function ()
    { // if trigger is hovered over

        jQuery('.hidden').animate({ opacity: 1 }, 250); // reveal the hidden element
    }, function () { // if mouse leaves the hover area
        jQuery('.hidden').animate({ opacity: 0 }, 250);
    }); // hide the hidden element again
});
```

Good luck...

Comment: This will not work. You'll need to target the appropriate item on hover - you're currently targeting all of them.

Comment: If he/she could provide with the HTML that's being used then it could help know how to navigate the layout. Above I showed how to target a group of elements via a css class. The rest he should be able to add on as he/she knows their HTML Layout...!

Comment: Hello, I appreciate all your replies and responses. I'm using this code on this page: kyntronics.under-development.info/product-configurator As you can see each of the images has the text div over the top, only the second one fro the top right currently works when hovered. What I need is to be able to hide all the text boxes, then only show the one on the image hovered over? This is why I thought I needed separate DIV and class elements.